# How can i execute below mongo db query

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-negation

```
{
   "$and":[ {
         "mobile_nos":{
            "$regex":{
               "regex":"^((?!Nagpur).)*$",
               "flags":"i"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "full_name":{
            "$regex":{
               "regex":"^((?!pune).)*$",
               "flags":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Above MongoDB query doesn't yield any result because the `mobile_nos` field does not exist in the document.

So how can I change the query so that it returns a result if field doesn't exist in document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following query which uses the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator for the logical condition that use the regex search if the the field exists OR don't use it if the field does not exist (with the **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator).

No need to specify the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator in the case since MongoDB provides an implicit `AND` operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit `AND` with the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions:

```
{
   "$or": [ 
        {
            "mobile_nos": {
                "$regex": {
                   "regex": "^((?!Nagpur).)*$",
                   "flags": "i"
                }
            }
        },
        { "mobile_nos": { "$exists": false } }
    ],
    "full_name": {
        "$regex": {
            "regex": "^((?!pune).)*$",
            "flags": "i"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) with [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
{
 "$and":[ {
        $or:[
        {
         "mobile_nos":{
            "$regex":{
               "regex":"^((?!Nagpur).)*$",
               "flags":"i"
            }
         },
         {
          "mobile_nos":{
            $exists: false
          }
         }
        ]
       }
      },
      {
         "full_name":{
            "$regex":{
               "regex":"^((?!pune).)*$",
               "flags":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```